# Gmail CAPTCHA is always wrong

Tags: gmail, captcha

I am trying to create an email account on Gmail shorter that 20 characters. Besides all the names that are already registered, it requires me to enter CAPTCHA every other new name and despite I am sure I am entering it right keeps saying it is wrong and shows another one.

Is there any solution to this problem?

Please do not suggest contacting Gmail support, it does not exist.

Comment: Are you sure you're not a computer?

Comment: Caps lock on? :)

Answer (score 2):

Interesting, yesterday I also tried to register a new gmail account. Looks like the policy is:

- For the first few times (not sure how many) you "check for name availability", no captcha is displayed
- After that they require you to be human, I guess this is an attempt to stop a script from probing their whole user base

The bad thing is, the captcha cannot be entered correctly. I'm quite sure I'm a human and my FF doesn't have any plugin or ad-don, except for DownThemAll. The workaround involves refreshing the page and/or restarting the browser. If that doesn't help try clearing cookies and/or wait a few minutes so that they "forget" you.